# WIKITUDE -Altitude parameter

Tags: android, augmented-reality, wikitude

Noob question:Ive just started to develop an AR application using Wikitude SDK. my target is a three floors building.I have a POI in the ground floor and another one in the second floor in the same location.I don't want the ground floor POI to show up when im currently in the second floor.so i would like to display the respective POI in the corresponding locations.getting the altitude of the same point using android apps and passing the altitude value in wikitude will it solve it?? or is there some other way i can meet the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Wikitude SDK, you can provide altitude information to each POI, and the phone delivers your current altitude through its sensors, so conceptually, your idea works. You check the altitude of each POI and your phone's current altitude, and only show those POIs which have the same altitude (minus a certain threshold).

Technically, however, you will run into issues when you get the current altitude from your phone. The altitude sensors from regular mobile devices will have an uncertainty of at least a couple of meters (or even tens of meters). That means you will not be 100% sure what floor you are in currently. The readings of the altitude values will be even worse (or the phone will tell you that it cannot get any useful altitude information at all) when you are inside a building. To get these proper altitude readings, you will require alternative localisation techniques (beacons etc.) to understand what floor you are in.

Best,
Martin